# Docker Build Fails with Connection Timeout to Debian Repositories

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, debian

I'm trying to build a Docker image using the `debian:testing-slim` base image. During the build process, I'm encountering connection timeouts when trying to connect to the Debian package repositories. Here's the error I'm seeing:

```
#8 62.09 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security testing-security InRelease
#8 62.10 Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing-updates InRelease
#8 63.10 Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing InRelease
#8 64.10 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security testing-security InRelease
#8 64.10 Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing-updates InRelease
#8 67.11 Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing InRelease
#8 67.11   Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (151.101.62.132), connection timed out
#8 68.10 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security testing-security InRelease
#8 68.10   Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (146.75.74.132), connection timed out
#8 68.10 Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing-updates InRelease
#8 68.10   Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:80:
```

I've tried switching to a different Debian mirror, but the issue persists. I'm using the following commands in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:testing-slim AS build-jni-library
RUN echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y ...
```

I've verified my internet connection is stable, and I'm not behind any restrictive firewall or VPN. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: If you comment out the first `RUN`, does it work ?

Comment: @Philippe it randomly started working again. i think there was actually an issue with their servers